# Why the mongoose $lte operator does not work as expected for comparing dates?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I am trying to compare dates to fetch records using mongoose query. The query is ,

> var docsByDateRange = await expense.find({user_id:user_id,date_of_expense: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } })

when I pass "endDate" in above query as a 31st of any month. The query fails to give expected result. It does not fetch record that has date something like "2022-03-31T11:32:40.000+00:00". Why? Does it have to do with timeZones n all?

Comment: You can compare ISODate to date, string to string or int to int (unix time). What types are you comparing? You are probably comparing string to date or to ISODate

Comment: Yes I am comparing string to date. What to do now?

Comment: How to convert mongoose date to string and compare?

Comment: Ok I will convert the string to date... as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date